# error shows when executing stored procedure using odbc

Tags: odbc, procedure, powerbuilder, timesten

My powerbuilder application connect to Oracle timesten database using odbc.

The application can connect to the databse and do dml (select, insert, update, delete) successfully.

But when I executie a stored procedure, an error is shown "driver not capable".

How can I solve it ?

Comment: How are you trying? Please add code examples.

Comment: As the message suggests, this is linked to the driver you use.  You should get the information for the driver you use (does it come from Oracle or Microsoft or third-party?)